# Posting hazardous materials information to Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

We are using MWS service to create/update items on Amazon marketplace. Everything is working fine except we are not able to send hazardous item info for an item through XML.

Which XML fields should we use for hazardous materials information?

Example Feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
-
instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn
-
envelop
e.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>M_SELLER_354577</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Op
erationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU>1Z
-
500ABR
-
FLAT</SKU>
<ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
<LaunchDate>2005
-
07
-
26T00:00:01</LaunchDate>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>Lyric 500 tc Queen Flat Sheet, Ivory</Title>
<Brand>Peaco
ck Alley</Brand>
<Description>Lyric sheeting by Peacock Alley is the epitome of simple and classic</Description>
<BulletPoint>made in Italy</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>500 thr
ead count</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>plain weave (percale)</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>100% Egyptian cotton</BulletPoint>
<Manufacturer>Peacock Alley</Manufacturer>
<SearchTerms>bedding</SearchTerms>
<SearchTerms>Sheets</SearchTerms>
<Item
Type>flat
-
sheets</ItemType>
<IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
<IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
<RecommendedBrowseNode>60583031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
<RecommendedBrowseNode>60576021<
/RecommendedBrowseNode>
</DescriptionData>
<ProductData>
<Home>
<Parentage>variation
-
parent</Parentage>
<VariationData>
<VariationTheme>Size
-
Color</VariationTheme>
</VariationData>
<Material>cotton</Material>
<
ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>
</Home>
</ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
<Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few fields in the XSD that deal with hazardous materials

1. There is the `<EUcompliance>` tag, but according to the XSD, that could only be used *instead* of `<Home>` which does not make any sense to me. For details look at Products.xsd and EUcompliance.xsd
2. There are `<HazmatItem>`s in `<FBA>` and `<ToysBaby>` but they share the same fate as the above. For details look at amzn-base.xsd for its definition and FBA.xsd and ToysBaby for its use. 
   I have no clue why neither is valid alongside other product types, but hey, that's what their XSDs say, and it's not the first time I'm puzzled what the schema designers at Amazon were thinking... so you're left with
3. Put it in `<OtherItemAttributes>` which is valid for all product types. It would go between `</ItemType>` and `<IsGiftWrapAvailable>`. For details look at products.xsd

I don't know why you'd want to include hazmat information in the feed, but that's where I'd put it.
(BTW, you have an extra  tag at the end which shouldn't be there)